# Is there an alternative for java system.setproperty?

Tags: java

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "cacerts.jks");

SSLSocketFactory ssf = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
```

I would want to implement my SSL socket for my server and client. There is this System.setproperty i am trying to replace with bufferedreader like stuff to read in the  certificate. Can it be done?

Comment: What framework, if any, are you using? (e.g. Axis, CXF, etc.)

Comment: you can have a lookaround on security :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15039869/system-setproperty-is-safe-in-java

Comment: You can manually create context with SSLContext.getInstance("SSL") and init it with trust factory.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure about reading the certificate, but you can make use of VM Arguments.
Eg: -DmyProp='propValue'

Refer: http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/whats-the-difference-between-program-arguments-and-vm-arguments.html