# Logback Dynamic Files using Two Properties

Tags: java, logback

my problem is : My application maintains three buildings, and each building has a different process.

So, using logback, I want to create a log which has a specification :
each building will have a specific folder, and inside that specific folder of each building, there will be many log files, with each log file indicates a process.

My logback.xml right now is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

<appender name="stdout" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
        </pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="logAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">
    <discriminator>
        <key>processName</key>
        <defaultValue>unknown</defaultValue>
    </discriminator>
    <sift>
        <appender name="FILE-${processName}"
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
            <file>logs/${distributor}/${processName}.log</file>
            <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
                <pattern>%d [%thread] %level %mdc %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
            </layout>
            <rollingPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
                <fileNamePattern>logs/${distributor}/${processName}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
                <minIndex>1</minIndex>
                <maxIndex>10</maxIndex>
                <!-- <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP"> 
                    <maxFileSize>5KB</maxFileSize> </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy> -->
            </rollingPolicy>
            <triggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </triggeringPolicy>
        </appender>
    </sift>
</appender>

<logger name="processLog" level="debug" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="logAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="stdout" />
</logger>

<root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="stdout" />
    <appender-ref ref="logAppender" />
</root>
</configuration>
```

And my java servlet code is :

```
public class DistributorServlet extends HttpServlet {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   private static Logger processLog = LoggerFactory.getLogger("processLog");

   protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
      String office = req.getParameter("office");
      MDC.put("distributor", office);
      String process = req.getParameter("process");
      MDC.put("process", process);
      processLog.debug("Processing");
   }
}
```

However, a log file is not generated.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. Make the below change

```
private static Logger processLog = LoggerFactory.getLogger("processLog");
```

to

```
private static Logger processLog = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DistributorServlet .class);
```

#### 2. Add additional discriminator for distributor

From the logback.xml it appears that only one `discriminator` has been added. Did you try adding another one for `distributor`

#### 3. Do not forget

To add `MDC.remove("keyName");` after its usage.

#### 4. In case if you observe issue with multiple MDC keys

I faced an issue with the `MDC.put` in trying to add multiple keys into it. (I wondered why no `putAll` has been defined)

Although the underlying implementation is that of a `HashMap<Key k, Value v>` that should allow adding multiple keys, I was only able to see that the last key you put into MDC would be applied to logback.xml

While for the other keys I observed `_IS_UNDEFINED` value that gets appended instead.

Of course then again you can refer to the other various links and although this may not be a best idea, here is what I have done in my Java code,

`System.setProperty("distributor", req.getParameter("office"));`

`System.setProperty("process", req.getParameter("process"));`

Modify the logback.xml by removing discriminator. Well, alternatively you can remove one of the above properties and have the MDC.put for that property.

However please do refer to the links [System.setProperty is safe in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15039869/system-setproperty-is-safe-in-java)

Alternatively I suggest https://stackoverflow.com/a/32615172/3838328