# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException when read from Properties file

Tags: java, multithreading, properties, log4j

I'm having trouble with reading JVM configuration properties with `System.getProperties()` due to the fact that in some environments I'm getting `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` after JVM restart.

> [err] java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
>   [err] at java.util.Hashtable$Enumerator.next(Hashtable.java:1502)

I have to restart multiple times the VM in order to avoid previous mentioned error.

What I have done until now:

- synchronized the method where the properties keys and values are being read and written to a log file;
- because Java's Properties object is a HashMap I have tried to use a synchronized Map;
- I have tried to simulate the concurrency issue by using more threads that share the same Properties object, however I have't been able to reproduce the error in my local envionment;
- I'm using StringBuffer due to the fact that is thread safe;

  ```
  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PropertyLogger.class);
  public static synchronized final void logProperties() {
          Level oldLevel = LOG.getLevel();
          LOG.setLevel(Level.INFO);
          Properties props = System.getProperties();
          Map<Object, Object> shared = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<>());
          shared.putAll(props);

          for (final Entry<Object, Object> entry : shared.entrySet()) {
            try{  StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
              buffer.append(entry.getKey());
              buffer.append(" = "); //$NON-NLS-1$
              buffer.append(entry.getValue());
              LOG.info(buffer.toString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
          LOG.setLevel(oldLevel);

      }
  ```

I could be that the problems I'm dealing with, are triggered also by log4j library, used for writting, which is far I know not thread safe.

I have added the stack trace:

> [err] java.util.ConcurrentModificationException [err] at
>   java.util.Hashtable$Enumerator.next(Hashtable.java:1502) [err] at
>   com.myapp.common.PropertyLogger.logProperties(PropertyLogger.java:23)
>   [err] at
>   com.myapp.input.ConfigurationServer.parse(ConfigurationServer.java:710)
>   [err] at
>   com.myapp.input.ConfigurationServer.configure(ConfigurationServer.java:94)
>   [err] at com.myapp.input.Application.run(Application.java:78) [err] at
>   com.myapp.input.servlet.InputStarter$ValidatorThread.run(InputStarter.java:113)

Regards,

PS: Should I add synchronized blocks to call the method? 
For example: In parse method should call my code with

```
synchronized(this) {
     PropertyLogger.logProperties();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not with the logging framework but with line

```
shared.putAll(props);
```

`Properties` class extends `Hashtable` and it is possible for the System properties to change at any time. With `shared.putAll(props)` you are iterating through the object `props` of `Properties(Hashtable)` class and if any value is modified during the iteration, we will get this error of `ConcurrentModificationException`

A solution would be to call clone() on the System.Properties() object before iterating

Comment: Hello Ashishkummar, before using Collections.synchronizedMap, I have used a HashMap for iterration ( Properties props = System.getProperties();
        for (final Entry<Object, Object> entry : props.entrySet())). The error mentioned in my question is from when I used a Hashmap not Collections.synchronizedMap. Thank you for your advice with clone call. I will try it.

Comment: I don't think HashMap or Collections.synchronizedMap in your code will cause this error. If you see the stack trace, there is HashTable method call

Comment: @SocketM It's not enough if you syncjronize the access to `System.getProperties()` in your code. Still other threads can call `System.getProperties()` without taking you synchronization into account, without being aware of it.

Comment: @LuCio so you recommend as Ashishkumar also recommended, to use a clone method before hand; this way you have a copy of the object at a certain point which will not be affected by change.

Comment: I don't know where your `ConcurrentModificationException` comes from. Please note [that](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/index.html?overview-summary.html) `Properties` _is thread-safe: multiple threads can share a single Properties object without the need for external synchronization._ (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15039996/2838289)).